# does "I'd say" mean "I think that"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

in this sentence what does i'd say mean:

> **I'd say** it hit the Nixons as bad as it did me when Danielle and myself broke up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right:

> I'd say ... / I would say ...

in this context means:

- I think that ...
- I have the opinion that ...
- I believe that ...

Comment: Note that *I'd say* ***on its own*** does not mean *I think that*. It's only in the context of this *specific* sentence that it has that meaning. (*"How would you say 'the car broken'?" "**I'd say** 'the car **is** broken.'"*)